# Add more objects to the array that is in the way - Just need to assign one object more compared to what is already there

Tags: c#

It's like I'm trying right now. To add more object to my array that I have.

When it's that I add. Then it adds in the array that I want to add with everything with user content.

This is what it looks like right now: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvJLH.png)

i try this here:

```
UserClass addUser = new UserClass()
{
    Businesses = new List<Business>()
    {
        new Business()
        {
            BusinessId = unikBusinessId,
            Name = add.BusinessName,
            CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Cvr = add.Cvr,
            priceId = add.HiddenPriceId,
            FreeUser = false
        }
    }
};
_accountService.AddBussinesMore(addBusiness, userid);
```

This is what it looks like right now, when I try to make it this way. [Error on add to Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5kmn.png)

UserClass:

```
public class UserClass
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    ........ (MORE HERE) .......

    public List<Business> Businesses { get; set; }

}
```

Business:

```
public class Business
{
    public string BusinessId { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public int Cvr { get; set; }

    public string priceId { get; set; }

    public bool FreeUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't have an array, you have a `List<T>`.

Comment: Its hard to see how the description of the problem maps to the code and the service. Is there any reason you can't just do `new List<Business>() { new Business() {...}, new Business() {...}`

Comment: I have complete this! Thanks for help @MichaelRandall